# iOS Facebook SDK - FBLoginView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

For some reason I cannot get this code to work:

```
// Create Login View so that the app will be granted "status_update" permission.
FBLoginView *loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];

loginview.frame = CGRectOffset(loginview.frame, 5, 5);
loginview.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:loginview];

[loginview sizeToFit];
```

I call it in the viewdidload of my `ViewController`.

I have :

```
#import <Social/Social.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
#import <AdSupport/AdSupport.h>
```

And :

```
@interface FacebookVCViewController : UIViewController <FBLoginViewDelegate> {
```

The `loginView` is simply not showing up. What did I do wrong?

Comment: check it if loginview have UIView class type and also check rect of loginview

Comment: yeah its a uiview subclass.. and the origin x, y are : 50.000000 300.000000


    
    loginview.frame = CGRectMake(50, 300, 50, 50); doesnt change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

adding the FacebookSDKResources.bundle file to the project (making sure it copies it and adds to target) solves the problem.

FacebookSDKResources.bundle is located in:

```
 FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/Resources/FacebookSDKResources.bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

Call this code inside of viewDidApear method hopefully it will work

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me..
In interface Builder (Size Inspector) look for autosizing option.. REMOVE arrows in middle of box.. :) . No need to tweak with bundles or frameworks

[image]